# Reiniciar procesos .exe .bat en python o django

Tags: python, django

Me pregunto: ¿es posible reiniciar procesos .exe .bat en lenguaje python o django?

Básicamente están corriendo procesos en producción en servidores remotos. Lo que se necesita es automatizar el proceso evitando entrar a cada uno de ellos y reiniciar o matar cierto proceso desde ahí. El objetivo es crear un sitio web que pueda administrar dichos procesos desde cualquier lugar con conexión.

Igualmente conectarse a un servidor remoto para administrar dichos procesos, ¿es posible hacerlo con este lenguaje y el framework?
y ¿como sería?.

Comment: Hola, tal vez puedes describir un poco más el problema. Si lo que quieres es la administración de procesos puedes hacerlo usando herramientas como [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/)

Comment: Especifica mejor lo que quieres. Si hablas de django, es que quieres python-3.x; si hablas de .exe/.bat es que lo quieres para windows. Porque podría decir que mires fabric, por ejemplo, y no servirte de nada. Y si puedes, añade algo de lo que has mirado o probado.

Comment: Gracias por responder, basicamente estan corriendo procesos en produccion en servidores remotos, lo que se necesita es automatizar el proceso evitando entrar a cada uno de ellos y reiniciar o matar cierto proceso desde ahi, el objetivo es crear un sitio web que pueda administrar dichos procesos desde cualquier lugar con conexion.

Comment: @matteo agregué esto mismo en la pregunta. Si hay algo que quieras agregar, no dudes en [edit] la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He trabajado con ese tipo de cosas, pero en ambientes Linux, utilizando fabric, es de lo mejor, pero en tu caso, que al parecer es Windows, se complica un poco.

Lo que yo intentaría serían 2 cosas...

1. Instalar Servidor SSH: [How To Get SSH Command-Line Access to Windows 7 Using Cygwin](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/), y con esto ya puedes automatizar en cientos de servidores remotos utilizando [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/)
2. Crear un Servidor y cliente con la librería de bajo nivel de Python Socket, o utilizando el framework de red Twisted, que a mi me ha gustado mucho (No puedo publicar mas vínculos...).

Comment: Gracias Robert!